# React Navigation goBack() with deep linking

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to implement deep linking through the linking interface exposed by React Navigation. Now handling deep links is working fine, however navigating after linking opened a screen for you is not working. Here is how my navigators look:

```
AuthedNavigator: {
    MainTabNav,
    ProfileNav: {
        ProfileScreen,
        EditProfile
    }
}
```

Now my deep-link should open the ProfileScreen view of the Profile navigator that is nested inside AuthedNavigator (this is working). ProfileNav has a header with a back button that calls navigation.goBack(). When the user presses on that, they should navigate back to MainTabNav (this is not working).

I thought [initialRouteName](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#rendering-an-initial-route) would do the trick, but it does not... Here is how my linking config looks like:

```
config: {
    screens: {
        Profile: {
            initialRouteName: 'MainTabNav',
            screens: {
                ProfileScreen: 'profile/:pubkey',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

When moved to `DeepLink`, the `app` will be re-run from the beginning, and the existing stack will be initialized and stacked into the moved `DeepLink` stack. Therefore, if you want to reset the `Tab screen`, you must randomly specify a stack.

you can use [`getStateFormPath`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#linkinggetstatefrompath)

- Example

```
const linkConfig = {
    screens: {
        MainTabNav,
        Other: "other",
    }
};

export const deepLink = {
    prefixes: ["my-app://"],
    config: linkConfig,
    getStateFromPath: (path: string, options?: Options<typeof linkConfig>) => {
        const state = getStateFromPath(path, options);
        const isTabPath = path.includes("tab");
        const originRoutes = state?.routes ?? [];
        const newState = {
            ...state,
            routes: isTabPath ? originRoutes : [{ name: "MainTabNav" }, ...originRoutes]
        };

        return newState;
    }
};
```

Comment: @Egge If my answer helped you with your question, please check your answer and vote.

Comment: Same issue found with expo deep linking as back button not working.
Try solution given by @hong developer but not working